# Webpack: require.ensure and extra vendor bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

My website has two kind of pages:

Pages where javascript widgets are the main content of the page (TypeA) and where widgets are some additional content, that user might to trigger (TypeB).

So I'd like to split my JS codebase into three bundles:

- `vendor.js` -- which is included on all pages
- `runtime.js` -- for widgets
- specific entry points for different pages

For TypeA-pages I have this:

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<script src="runtime.js"></script>
<script src="pageA.js"></script>
<!-- pageA.js launches the widget -->
```

But for TypeB I want this:

```
<script src="vendor.js"></script>
<scriprt>
  <!-- pseudo code -->
  when('user clicks button', function() {
    require.ensure('pageB.js', function(require) {
        var pageBCode = require('pageB.js');
        <!-- do the magic -->
        <!-- but I also need runtime.js here -->
    });
  });
</script>
```

The problem is, that I want to reuse `runtime.js` in both *sync* and *async* pages. But I can't figure out **how to load `runtime.js` along with my on-demand loading `pageB.js`**. I still have to include it via `<script src="runtime.js"></script>`.

(I use `CommonChunksPlugin` for creating `vendor.js` and `runtime.js`, and it works well on TypeA pages)

Comment: Why cant you do something like this `require.ensure(['pageB.js', 'runtime.js'], ....)`

Comment: You can use [`bundle-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader) to load bundled files

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array to `require.ensure` as such:

```
require.ensure(['pageB.js','runtime.js'], function(require){
  var pageBCode = require('pageB.js'),
      runtimeCode = require('runtime.js');

  /** MAGIC! **/
});
```

Comment: `runtime.js` is not a module, but a bundle itself. (It's built from many other files)

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible, but u say that it's a bundle, i assume it was bundled by using webpack as well, in this case you can create a module that  requires everything in `runtime.js`

Comment: @jkris check my comments